# How do I join pairs of consecutive lines in a large file (1 million lines) using vim, sed, or another similar tool?

Tags: vim, sed, large-files, text-processing

I need to move the contents of every second line up to the line above such that line2's data is alongside line1's, either comma or space separated works.

Input:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

Output:

```
line1 line2
line3 line4
```

I've been doing it in vim with a simple recording but vim seems to crash when I tell it to do it 100 000 times...  I'm thinking maybe sed would be a good alternative but not sure how to do what I want or maybe there's a better option?

Each line only contains 1 numerical value, I just have a million lines...

Comment: Please format your question, and show us proper input and expected output.

Answer (score 20):

If I understand correctly, you have:

```
line1 
line2
line3
line4
...
```

and you want:

```
line1<SEP>line2
line3<SEP>line4
```

then you can do it easily with `(g)awk` like this:

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { o=$0 ; next } { print o "<sep>" $0 }' INPUTFILE
```

[See it in action here](https://ideone.com/CvFNU).

*Update*: if the number of lines is odd, the above will omit the last line (as Martin Stettner pointed out) so this will not:

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { o=$0 ; next } { print o "<sep>" $0 } END { if ( NR % 2 == 1 ) { print o } }' INPUTFILE
```

HTH

Comment: Wouldn't this script omit the last line in case you have an odd number of lines?

Answer (score 19):

The paste command can do this.  Its "-s" option will join consecutive lines; and the "-d" option specifies a list of characters to use as delimiters, repeating them cyclically.  Join first with a space, then with a newline, and repeat:

```
seq 10 | paste -sd" \n" -
```

Comment: best answer The '-' at the end is not necessary because paste reads from input as default.

Comment: The trailing '-' is required by some versions of paste (such as MacOS)

Answer (score 11):

This might work for you:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' file
```

Or

```
cat file | paste -d' ' - -
```

Or another couple of ways for the above:

```
paste -d\  - - <file

paste -sd' \n' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the `paste` example - I'd never noticed you could specify the "same file" (stdin) twice!

Answer (score 10):

try this:

```
sed -rn 'N;s/\n/ /;p' yourFile
```

test with seq:

```
kent$  seq 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

kent$  seq 10|sed -rn 'N;s/\n/ /;p'
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

awk works too:

```
awk 'NR%2{printf $0" ";next;}1' yourFile
```

test

```
kent$  seq 10|awk 'NR%2{printf $0" ";next;}1'
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

Answer (score 8):

<del>Well your example is this in Vim.</del>

<del>`:g/^/+t.|-j`</del>

<del>But then what about the last line?</del>

<del>Or did you mean this?</del>

```
:g/^/j
```

You might also be interested in this Vim script, which makes dealing with large files easier.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506

Comment: Hi,wow, i knew there had to be a better way than I was trying!! :)  Thanks for the loads of options, :g/^/j was the most simple and does the job great!

Comment: Edited the OP following the above clarification above. The first suggestion in my answer can now be ignored.

Comment: Great Vim tip! In my case, wasn't the whole file, so can use a Visual Selection `:'<,'>g/^/j` or between the _a mark_ and the current line `:'a,.g/^/j` to limit the joining to my range of interest. Beats doing it 773 times manually!

Answer (score 3):

```
$ seq 10 | sed '2~2G' | awk -v RS='' '{$1=$1; print}'
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

---

```
$ paste -d' ' <(sed -n 'p;n' num.txt) <(sed -n 'n;p' num.txt)
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

---

```
$ echo -e 'g/^/,+1j\n%p' | ex num.txt
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

---

```
$ seq 10 | awk 'NR%2{printf("%s ", $0); next}1'
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

---

```
$ seq 10 | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

**note:** `$ seq 10 >num.txt`

Comment: How about `perl`? `seq 10 | perl -pe '$a++%2||s/\n/ /'`

Answer (score 2):

```
seq 10 | awk 'ORS=NR%2?FS:RS'
```

This solution uses "ternary operator" to set `ORS`

```
ORS= ....... output register separator (will receive =)
NR%2 ....... test if it has division remainder of Number of Register by 2
?FS:RS ..... FS = "space" RS = "\n" (newline)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may utilize [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) for this.
Usually `xargs` takes as many input elements as possible and executes some command with the elements read as arguments. E.g.

```
cat file | xargs
```

would echo

```
line1 line2 line3 line4
```

But you can limit the number of lines read with option `-n`

```
cat file | xargs -n 2
```

will have the desired effect of joining every two lines:

```
line1 line2
line3 line4
```

If the lines may contain white space, you must specify the input delimiter (newline) explicitly

```
cat file | xargs -n 2 -d '\n'
```

---

And finally, don't use [`cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) this way, say instead

```
xargs -n 2 -d '\n' <file
```

or even

```
xargs -n 2 -d '\n' -a file
```