# Regex to club consecutive lines?

Tags: regex, sed

I have text file like  this

```
name1
age1
name2
age2
name3
age3
name4
age4
```

I want the data in this format

```
name1:age1
name2:age2
name3:age3
name4:age4
```

Can anyone suggest me any regular expression to achieve such results? I am using eclipse regular expression which works the same way as notepad++ or edit+ regular expression. Also can it be done through sed in bash in linux?

Comment: Find what: `(\w+)\n(\w+)`. Replace with `$1:$2`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I join pairs of consecutive lines in a large file (1 million lines) using vim, sed, or another similar tool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545538/how-do-i-join-pairs-of-consecutive-lines-in-a-large-file-1-million-lines-using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 'N;s/\n/:/' file
name1:age1
name2:age2
name3:age3
name4:age4
```

`N` appends next line to the Pattern space buffer.

Through paste,

```
$ paste -d':' - - < file
name1:age1
name2:age2
name3:age3
name4:age4
```

Comment: simple and efficient, maybe the last `g` not needed to be perfect

Answer (score 0):

Since sed solution is  already provided which is the best, analternative with awk:

```
>awk 'NR%2==0{print x":"$0}{x=$0}' your_file
name1:age1
name2:age2
name3:age3
name4:age4
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",$1,(NR%2==0?RS:":")}' file
name1:age1
name2:age2
name3:age3
name4:age4
```

It can be written like this, but it may not work on all system:

```
awk '{printf $1(NR%2==0?RS:":")}' file
```

---

Here is an shorter `awk`

```
awk 'ORS=NR%2?":":RS' file
name1:age1
name2:age2
name3:age3
name4:age4
```

This is very flexible.  If you like to join every `3rd` line, just change to `NR%3` ...

---

Here is another `past` (one of the shortest solution here)

```
paste -sd":\n" file
name1:age1
name2:age2
name3:age3
name4:age4
```