# up line that start with specifc string

Tags: linux, csh, tcsh

How can I take line up if string start with a specific word?

file:

```
My name
is kuku
My name
is pupu
My name
is yoyo
```

Output should be:

```
My name is kuku
My name is pupu
My name is yoyo
```

I tried the below command but look I'm missing something...

```
sed s=^is=\r is=g' file
```

Comment: Anyone can help? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `awk`-based solution that doesn't require doing any math at all, using only built-in variables and nothing else:

**INPUT**

```
My name
is kuku
My name
is pupu
My name
is yoyo
```

**CODE**

```
{m,g}awk 'ORS = ORS!=OFS ? OFS : RS' FS='^$'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
My name is kuku
My name is pupu
My name is yoyo
```

The most condensed edition, if you don't care for `FS` efficiency, would be

```
awk 'ORS=RS<ORS?RS:" "'
```

Answer (score 0):

**awk** is your friend:

```
$awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { o=$0 ; next } { print o " " $0 }' file
```

Source:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545538/how-do-i-join-pairs-of-consecutive-lines-in-a-large-file-1-million-lines-using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1ksX.jpg)

In English:

- Iterate through the file
- If the line number is odd
  remember it and skip
- Else
  paste remembered line with the current (i.e. even) line separated by space

  [image]